# How can I convert a Codable's property with type Double in a given JSON as Date using Decoder?

Tags: json, swift, codable, dateformatter

I have a problem decoding the below JSON:

```
{
    ...

    "date": 20200202000000,

    ...
}
```

I know the formatting is something like this `yyyyMMddhhmmss`.

My `Codable` struct is this:

```
struct MyCodableStruct: Codable{

    let date: Date

}
```

I would like to create a `DateFormatter` like this:

```
static let customFormater: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    return formatter
}()
```

so I can set my `JSONDecoder` easily like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(customFormater)
```

but as it may be obvious to you this doesn't work because it should be defined as a `String` but now its an `Int` (I guess so..).

It says:

> Expected to decode String but found a number instead.

So, how can I convert a `Codable`'s property with type of `Date` in a given JSON that it's property is `Int` instead using `Decoder`?

Comment: Not related to your question but you should set your DateFormatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" and calendar before setting the formatter's dateFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `.formatted` `dateDecodingStrategy`, you'll have to go one level deeper and use the `.custom` one to do the decoding yourself, converting it from an `Int` to a `String` manually:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ decoder in
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let dateAsInteger = try container.decode(Int.self)
    let dateAsString = "\(dateAsInteger)"
    guard let date = WhateverTypeContainsCustomFormatter.customFormatter.date(from: dateAsString) else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Could not form Date from value: \(dateAsString)")
    }

    return date
})
```

(Replace `WhateverTypeContainsCustomFormatter` with... well, whatever type of yours that contains your `customFormatter`.)